# Посчитать количество одинаковых элементов в списке Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict

Нужно, пройтись по буквам в строке списка, если у словаря нет такого ключа, значит создаём, и задаём значение 1, если есть то добавляем 1. Использовать Counter нельзя.
Вот что написал я

```
def dickt(string):
    k = {}
    for i in string:
        k += i
    return k

u = {'abbccc'}
print(dickt(u))
```

Answer (score 2):

Если правильно понимаю конечную цель задания:

```
from collections import Counter

s = 'this is test string'
print(dict(Counter(s)))
```

Результат:

```
{'s': 4, 't': 4, 'n': 1, 'e': 1, 'i': 3, 'r': 1, 'g': 1, ' ': 3, 'h': 1}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое))

Answer (score 1):

```
def dickt(string):
    k = {}
    for i in string:
        if i in k:
            k[i] += 1
        else:
            k[i]=1
    return k

u = 'abbccc'
print(dickt(u))
```