# Подсчитать количество элемента и вывести

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пользователь должен сам задавать последовательность.
Дана строка символов; подсчитать, сколько раз среди символов строки
встречается буква "x".
В принципе, задача не сложная, просто не могу понять, что здесь не работает:

Делю последовательность на отдельные элементы, затем задаю условие, что когда встречается этот элемент, при помощи count  подсчитываю количество элементов.

```
n = list()
n = input("Введите последовательность:  ")
n.split()
i = 0
for i in n :
    i+=1
    if (i=='x'):
        s.count('x')
print(n)
```

Comment: `n.split()` - **возвращает** разделенную строку, а не делит её.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов если вы знаете как реализовать данную задачу прошу помочь,так как еще учусь(

Comment: `s.count('x')` вернёт количество символов `x` в **строке** `s`. Вот и вся задача.

Comment: @whizz169 спасибо большое,2 вариант оказался рабочим

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Посчитать количество одинаковых элементов в списке Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/907874/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы сначала пишете `n = list()` а потом этот же n у вас становится `input()`, одной переменной присваиваете разные значения. Если хотите завернуть в список введенную строку то можно сделать `list(input().split())`
Или так, если вводите последовательность через пробел:

```
n = [i for i in input("Введите последовательность:  ").split()]

x = n.count('x')
print(x)
```

Или проще, если вводите любую строку:

```
n = input("Введите последовательность:  ")

x = n.count('x')
print(x)
```